# Deployment tools ENTERPRISE - what is the best for Windows environment?

Tags: .net, c++, windows, deployment

What is the "best" tool for creating deployment packages/jobs/stuff for all "enterprise level" deployments.....
GAC, COM+, Credentials, App pools, Web sites, registry entries, etc... It would be best if there is a way to "tokenize" the credentials and registry entries so that we can enter the appropriate credentials for the "next" environment.  Assume there are 7 environments in the enterprise predev, dev, integrated test, user test, prod, pfix , training each needing it's own set of credentials
What are you using to migrate an INTERNAL WEBSITE to your corporate environment (even if external users access it).... 
We will need Audit logging, reporting, rollback, Multiple server deployment, ability to remove a server from cluster, stop services, deploy "everything" and start everything back up and then place server back in the cluster....
Is anyone actually USING anything they like where there is minimal "scripting" required.

Answer (score 1):

Power Shell, actually

Comment: He does ask for minimal "scripting"... but I agree with you still.